# Finding the greatest lower bound of a finite lattice

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, lattice-orders

For the lattice below. What is the Greatest Lower Bound of $a_2$ and $a_4$ (i.e., $a_2 \land a_4$) and $a_3$ and $a_4$ (i.e. $a_3 \land a_4$)?

[image]

I thought it was $a_2 \land a_4 = a_2$ and $a_3 \land a_4= a_3$, but I got it wrong on the homework and I don't know what the right answer is.

Can someone tell me what the Greatest Lower Bound is and why?

Comment: You are right. Are you sure that was the exact problem?

Comment: @amrsa Yeah, I did an operation table on the meets and joins and he pointed those two as being incorrect

Comment: It must be an error from the marker of the homework. Talk to that person and check what's going on